# Why does my Flask API endpoint get a CORS error, but other similarly programmed endpoints do not?

Tags: python, http, flask, cors, backend

### Problem

I have a Flask API with two different kinds of routes. I am making requests to my API endpoints from a JavaScript/D3.js application. I need help troubleshooting a CORS error.

### Endpoint format

One kind of endpoint follows the format `http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v0.1.0/infrastructure/primary_type/secondary_type`

And the other kind follows the format `http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v0.1.0/infrastructure/primary_type/`

I am getting a CORS error for the one following the format `http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v0.1.0/infrastructure/primary_type/`

### CORS Error

`Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v0.1.0/infrastructure/primary_type' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

### Endpoint Code

#### Working Endpoint

```
@bp.route("<primary_type>/<secondary_type>")
def get_infrastructure(primary_type, secondary_type):
    infrastructure = ''
    if primary_type == 'null':
        infrastructure = shotgun_api.db.infrastructure.find({'properties.type.secondary': secondary_type}, projection = {'_id': False})
    else:
        infrastructure = shotgun_api.db.infrastructure.find({"$and": [{'properties.type.primary': primary_type},{'properties.type.secondary': secondary_type}]}, projection = {"_id": False})    
    
    response = jsonify([resource for resource in infrastructure])
    response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    return response
```

#### Endpoint triggering errors

```
@bp.route('<primary_type>/')
def get_by_primary_type(primary_type):
    infrastructure = shotgun_api.db.infrastructure.find({'properties.type.primary': primary_type}, projection = {'_id': False}) 
    response = jsonify([resource for resource in infrastructure])
    response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    return response
```

#### Expected behavior

I would expect that using the same `response.headers.add...` code would provide me with a `200 OK` status but it only works for the more complex endpoint for some reason.

### Client Side JavaScript/D3.js

```
for (let i = 0, num_draw_props = lyr.draw_props.length; i < num_draw_props; ++i) {
          start_loading_layer();
          Promise.all(lyr.draw_props[i].src.map(x => lyr.draw_props[i].d3_fetch(x)))
            .then(function(files) {
              lyr.context.restore();
              lyr.context.save();
              return files;
            }).then(files => {
              transform_layer(lyr.context, transform);
              return files
            }).then(files => {
              console.time('draw_layer')
              lyr.draw_props[i].draw_layer(lyr.context, files);
              console.timeEnd('draw_layer')
            });
        }
```

Where `d3_fetch` is equal to `d3.json()`. When `src` is `'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v0.1.0/infrastructure/mines/coal'` everything works fine, but when `src` is `http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v0.1.0/infrastructure/railroads` I get the previously mentioned CORS error.

### What I've tried

I have tried using Flask-CORS but was unable to get it accessible to my application despite installing it with pip. I would prefer to solve this without using Flask-CORS. I am otherwise at a loss for what to do here and any advice is appreciated.